# CPU usage 100% till i open task manager in a 4 months old laptop

Tags: windows-10, malware, anti-virus, high-cpu-usage

I have had an i5 10th Gen machine for 4 months, but I can now see that the CPU usage is 100% till I open Task Manager and as the Task Manager opens, the usage reduces drastically and even comes to as low as 4 percent.

I seriously have no idea what the problem is, as I tried updating something that Windows 10 wanted me to, and also ran a anti-malware and full system scan separately using Quick Heal Antivirus, but neither of these worked.

Also, my memory usage is sometimes considerably high too,  as I only get only 4 to 5 GB usable RAM out of 8GB. Could someone please give me a solution to these problems in a point wise manner?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To help narrow down the issue, could you perhaps edit your question  to indicate how you measure the CPU usage before opening task manager? Could you also indicate what you've searched for so far and what those searches brought you? This prevents that people suggest things you've already tried.

Comment: How do you know CPU % before opening Task Manager? It is now completely normal for Task Manager to show 100% for several seconds and then drop back to low CPU. This happened about half way through Windows 10 versions from beginning to now. If you perceive a fault, return it under warranty.

Comment: @john,sir what do you mean by if i percieve it as a fault i can return it as the return window was for only 7 days and now i can only have it repaired and please tell it in some more detail as i am not very technically sound and yes when i open task manager it shows 100% cpu usage for like 2-3 seconds and then starts falling down is it really normal cause i read somewhere that it is due to malwares and stuff please tell me if it is normal and happens on your machines too or a virus and if it is a virus what measures should i take.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke the way i got to know about cpu usage was by opening task manager ik i went a but off track with question. The problem is that when i open task manager it shows 100% cpu usage for some seconds and in the next few seconds it goes down to around 4%. I tried malware scans but it seems clean i used the quick heal antivirus software do you any other software from which i can check it again or is it just normal. And can you suggest me some ways to bring down usable memory it would be really nice

Comment: You said "The problem is that when i open task manager it shows 100% cpu usage for some seconds and in the next few seconds it goes down to around 4%."   <-- That is now (and has been for a year or so) completely normal

Comment: thank you so much @John and can you tell me the reason behind it and yea what were you saying about returning my machine can you elaborate on that. I am sorry if i am asking too , much but yea i am a bit clingy sometimes

Comment: If it is just Task Manager then you should be fine.

Comment: @John  if there is bit of a fault in task manager how else can i check cpu usage without opening task manager ?

Comment: Try Admin Tools, Resource Monitor to double check.  The way Task Manager works now is not a fault

Comment: so you mean that it is the task manager which when launches uses up the cpu upon initialising as it has to gather so much information right ??

Comment: and yea when i looked up in resource monitor cpu looks fine but there is something called maximum frequency that is going beyond 100% what's that ?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke My pc shows the same symptoms. I have a separate h/w monitor app that shows cpu usage in the tray and the laptop fan speed also goes up with more noise. As I open the task manager to know which app is causing it the usage goes down.

Comment: @d-coder What issue are you actually having? A high CPU usage is not a problem in itself, unless it prevents you from doing something. If you've figured that out best is to search previous answers and then ask a new question, including your previous research.

Comment: Should the fact that Windows 10 takes 3-4 Gbs of RAM on it's own surprise anyone?

Answer (score 0):

This is completely normal. Your CPU usage isn't actually 100%. This is just Task Manager loading up. It takes a few seconds after opening it to load and retrieve current usage data.

When opening Task Manager, it will freeze for a few seconds and display inaccurate and vague numbers, then begin to display the correct data. This is normal behaviour and is how Task Manager works, there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: ok so i am sure its not a problem then . Do you have any way to free up RAM i sometimes only get 4 gb or less usable under normal usage also some people say it is my antivirus software which is to some extent true as i saw it hogging a bit of space but leaving that aside do you have any other method to free up some RAM. No very noticeable peformance change though but still i wanna keep things in cool in my machine.

Comment: I'd recommend asking a new question for that, such as, 'How to free up RAM', etc

Comment: If my answer helped, click on the green tick and the up arrow to let people know that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

This happens on my Windows 10 machine as well - at least as long as I'm understanding your question right.

When I open Task Manager, it says 100% cpu, but as Task Manager loads, it immediately drops and then reads normally.

**If you don't notice performance issues, you don't have an issue here** it's just an oddity of how Task Manager is working. If you **are** actually experiencing performance issues here then you have cause for concern.

You can always use [Performance Monitor](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-performance-monitor-windows-10#:%7E:text=Open%20Start%2C%20do%20a%20search,Management%2C%20and%20click%20on%20Performance.) (built in to Windows, not a 3rd party software), and log the CPU usage. I'd be willing to bet that if you had Perf Mon open, and it was reading 4%, then you opened Task Manager, you'd see 100% in Task Manager until it loaded while Perf Mon showed the 4%.

If you were truly at 100% CPU you wouldn't be able to open Task Manager, your PC would be for the most part unusable.

Comment: i am not facing any noticeable performance issues and yea did you mean resource monitor as i cant find cpu usage section in performance monitor and yes in the resource monitor it shows 4% but still 100% percent for a few seconds in task manager

Comment: photos sometime loads a bit slow thats it and i think thats normal

Comment: I have the same issue but my win-10 machine is running in a vm so I can monitor the CPU of the vm.  As soon as I open task manager both the CPU of windows 10 and the CPU of the vm drop to 10 to 15% of one CPU.  I do observe the momentary surge in CPU from task manager starting.

Answer (score 0):

is your computer showing 100 disk usage constantly. is it slow to respond. this is a pretty common issue especially for laptop users. but it can be maddening to figure out why it's happening or how to stop it. however there are a few likely culprits clogging up your computer's storage bandwidth to start you can check your disk usage by opening up the task manager in windows 11 or 10. you need to fix [100% disk usage](https://newscutzy.com/windows/100-disk-usage-in-windows-11-ram-memory/) as well as [speed up your windows 11 or 10 system](https://newscutzy.com/windows/speed-up-windows-11-gaming-optimization/) even gaming time.

Answer (score 0):

if you see this error you must clean your C: Drive to do this follow the steps below!

- Press windows+s and type 'clean' and hit enter button the hit 'ok'
- Then click on 'clean up system files.' hit ok
  [image]
- Now check all options and click on ok

and if still having the same try 9 other methods that I read on [techocen](https://techocen.com/fix-waasmedic-agent-exe-high-disk-usage/)

Answer (score -1):

no one can say with out a test(see after format your PC, my advise. and better to tracking your CPU with HWMonitor. if it overheat even nothing is running). sometime it could be a Cryptojacking . they use your pc to mining their Bitcoin.

sometime i use taskMan too to track the background of the task Manager. most of Cryptojacking  always programmed to close after open task manager

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a very confusing message. Are you recommending that the OP should format their PC and then follow your advise? I'd recommend you read [how to make a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer), then edit this. If you don't want to do that, you should delete this. [Low quality answers can lead to an answer ban](https://superuser.com/help/answer-bans). This [will very likely be deleted anyway](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers) for the poor quality, but doing it yourself will save others the trouble.